# Looking for Task.IsPending

Tags: task-parallel-library

I often do something like this:

```
if (task != null && !task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
{
    // do something, e.g. cancel the task
}
```

It would be great to have `task.IsPending` as a shortcut for `!task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted`, but it's not there. And `task.Status == TaskStatus.Running` is not the same, as task can be in one of the waiting states.

I have a custom `Task` extension method for this, but I'm curious why it is not there in the first place. Is checking for pending status this way considered somehow deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just looking for:

```
if (task != null && !task.IsCompleted)
```

As documented, [`IsCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted.aspx) covers faulted and canceled states as well as `RanToCompletion`:

> `IsCompleted` will return true when the task is in one of the three final states: `RanToCompletion`, `Faulted`, or `Canceled`.

Comment: @Noseratio Why use Reflector when it's in the documentation?